# What kind of sandwich can be made with Shredded Beef?

Tags: beef, sandwich

it's my first time asking here so I am not exactly sure if this question is off-topic or not. So here's the question. My mother made something with shredded beef. I contains a little amount of greens and is quite tangy. It's been in the freezer for quite long now and whenever I look at it I vision a sandwich. Thing is, I don't what to make it with.
The most daunting part about it to me is finding a right binding agent that'll keep the beef from falling out of the bread slices.
Any ideas people?
Also any sauce you could recommend with it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A shredded beef sandwich (you asked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know what the flavor profile of the shredded beef, but a nice flavorful hummus (Sabra is my favorite brand) is one of my favorite alternates to mayonnaise in beef sandwiches. Sounds unusual, but it's a great textural and flavor compliment.

Comment: @Katey: you're talking about a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawarma

Comment: I've never had a shawarma with beef and hummus, only with lamb / tahini and yogurt sauce, but I am not surprised at all that I didn't invent this sandwich. I also dip these roast beef / hummus sandwiches in Annie's Goddess dressing, which is a dressing made of tahini and cider vinegar.

Answer (score 2):

Binding agent?  What you describe sounds to me like it'd make a good pulled beef sandwich ... you might need some soft rolls and a lot of napkins, but you likely don't need any binder if the flavor's already good.

If you're concerned with it being overly messy, buy some unsliced rolls, cut 'em yourself, and don't go all the way through, so there's still a sort of hinge on one side.  This will help to slow down the filling from ejecting when you eat it.

If you really insist on a binder, I'd look to some sort of thick sauce ... like some barbecue sauces, but you'd have to find something that matches the flavor of what you already have.

Comment: Maybe a mayonnaise would be good with beef.